# R: Dealing with time mismatches while using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Hey I'm trying to transition from using ddply to using data.table, and I'm close to figuring it out, but I have slight adjustments that I still need to make. Here's the summary of what I'm trying to do, using a toy data set:

Let's say I have sales data for two products for multiple weeks.

```
    x <- structure(list(week = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4), product = c("a", 
    "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), sold = c(10, 15, 20, 
    25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50)), .Names = c("week", "product", "sold"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
    ), sorted = c("product", "week"))

        week product sold
     1:    1       a   10
     2:    1       a   15
     3:    2       a   20
     4:    3       a   25
     5:    1       b   30
     6:    2       b   35
     7:    2       b   40
     8:    3       b   45
     9:    4       b   50
```

I want to find the total sales for product i for week j, i.e. I sold 25 units of product a for week 1.

I used the following code to do this:

```
    setDT(x)
    setkey(x,product,week)
    > x1 <- x[x,sum(sold)]
    > x1
       product week V1
    1:       a    1 25
    2:       a    1 25
    3:       a    2 20
    4:       a    3 25
    5:       b    1 30
    6:       b    2 75
    7:       b    2 75
    8:       b    3 45
    9:       b    4 50
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to remove the duplicate rows, ie. row 2 is redundant. Additionally, I also want to include NA for weeks where the product didn't sell, ie. a row for product a week 4 with value NA.

I'm sure this is an easy question and I know how to do this in ddply, but I couldn't find what I was looking for through searching. If anyone could help out or link me to the right page if this is a duplicate, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can cross join by unique products and all weeks, then sum each group.

```
> x[CJ(unique(product), 1:4), sum(sold), by=.EACHI]
   product week V1
1:       a    1 25
2:       a    2 20
3:       a    3 25
4:       a    4 NA
5:       b    1 30
6:       b    2 75
7:       b    3 45
8:       b    4 50
```

If you're using data.table version `<= 1.9.2`, then just remove the `by = .EACHI` part. It's a new design change from the next version on (currently implemented in 1.9.3 devel). Check out the [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/datatable/blob/master/NEWS) for more info on this.

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I was thinking of, didn't know there was a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reshaping is another option:

```
require(reshape2); require(data.table)
(dt2 <- dcast.data.table(dt, product ~ week, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "sold", fill = NA, drop = FALSE))
#   product  1  2  3  4
# 1:       a 25 20 25 NA
# 2:       b 30 75 45 50
(dt3 <- melt(dt2, id.vars = "product", variable.name = "week", value.name = "sold"))
#    product week sold
# 1:       a    1   25
# 2:       b    1   30
# 3:       a    2   20
# 4:       b    2   75
# 5:       a    3   25
# 6:       b    3   45
# 7:       a    4   NA
# 8:       b    4   50
```